# SUMPRODUCT data between range of dates in non consecutive columns

Tags: excel

OBJECTIVE
Sheet1 is the data. Col. I is the dates.  I want to sum Col. Q to U and Col. W to AA which fall between certain dates.

Sheet1

```
Col. I          |   Col. Q to  Col. U       |      Col. W to Col. AA    
01/01/2010      xxxxx   
02/01/2011      xxxxx  
04/01/2012      xxxxx
```

Data starts at row 9 ends at row 128

Sheet2 contains the beginning and ending dates.

Sheet2

```
Input Beginning Date:   E302
Input End Date:         F302
```

Sheet3 is the formula and output

Sheet3

```
SUMPRODUCT (((Sheet2!E302<='Sheet1'!I9:I128) *(Sheet2!F302>='Sheet1'!I9:I128)) 
 *'Sheet1'!Q9:U128+'Sheet1'!W9:AA128)
```

PROBLEM  & QUESTION:
The formula is simply adding up the data for all the dates and not the data for the particular range of dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the SUMPRODUCT you need to do two.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!E302<='Sheet1'!I9:I128)*(Sheet2!F302>='Sheet1'!I9:I128) *('Sheet1'!Q9:U128)) + SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!E302<='Sheet1'!I9:I128)*(Sheet2!F302>='Sheet1'!I9:I128) *('Sheet1'!W9:AA128))
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Options.

1. You can use a helper columns to sum each row and then do one sumifs off that.
2. Simply string together and addition of 10 Sumifs for each column.

Comment: SUMIFS can't sum multiple columns.

Comment: You can string two SUMIFS together.

Comment: Your solution works but I was looking for something a little more compact.  Thanks!